# Android : How to get the List of Installed apps that use Internet Access - PackageManager

Tags: android, package-managers

I wonder if it is possible, we get the list of Installed apps by :

```
    PackageManager pm = AppList.this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List   list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


        for ( ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
    {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));


        }
```

Can we sort or filter apps that use Internet Access to work?

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to retrieve the `PackageInfo` corresponding with an application, then examine its `requestedPermissions` array to see if the `INTERNET` permission is in there.

Answer (score 0):

This function will check an activity if it has the internet permission and if that permission is granted. You have to modify it accordingly for a service.

```
boolean checkIfUsesInet(ResloveInfo rInfo) {
  boolean result = false;
  try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(rInfo.activityInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    for(int i=0; i < packageInfo.requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
      String permission = packageInfo.requestedPermission[i];
      int permissionFlag = packageInfo.requestedPermissionFlags[i];
      if(Manifest.permission.INTERNET.equals(permission) && (permissionFlag & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0)
        result = true;
    }
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
}
```